# Strategies to wrap C API for C++ consumption

Tags: c++, c, c++11, design-patterns

In a C++ app I have to interface with a C library. This library has several components each with its own API. The APIs are very similar and differ just in the prefix of the functions and in some handler type. E.g.:

```
// bull component
void bull_create(bull_handle_t** handle, error_details_t* error_details);
void bull_destroy(bull_handle_t* handle, error_details_t* error_details);
void bull_get_data(bull_handle_t* handle, uint8_t* buffer, error_details_t* error_details);

// frog component
void frog_create(frog_handle_t** handle, error_details_t* error_details);
void frog_destroy(frog_handle_t* handle, error_details_t* error_details);
void frog_get_data(frog_handle_t* handle, uint8_t* buffer, error_details_t* error_details);

// bullfrog component
void bullfrog_create(bullfrog_handle_t** handle, error_details_t* error_details);
void bullfrog_destroy(bullfrog_handle_t* handle, error_details_t* error_details);
void bullfrog_get_data(bullfrog_handle_t* handle, uint8_t* buffer, error_details_t* error_details);

// NOTE: components can and will be added at any time following the same pattern.
```

I want to wrap this for C++ consumption in a generic way with minimal code duplication. 
So first the naive approach:

```
class bull_backend
{
public:
   ...
   void get_data (uint8_t* buffer)
   {
       error_details_t err;
       bull_get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
   }
   ...

private:
    bull_handle_t* handle;
};

class frog_backend
{
public:
   ...
   void get_data (uint8_t* buffer)
   {
       error_details_t err;
       frog_get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
   }
   ...

private:
    frog_handle_t* handle;
};

class bullfrog_backend
{
public:
   ...
   void get_data (uint8_t* buffer)
   {
       error_details_t err;
       bullfrog_get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
   }
   ...

private:
    bullfrog_handle_t* handle;
};
```

That does not quite cut it. I will be just duplicating the C API but now in the form of classes.
The only thing that is different is just the prefix which identifies the C entities.

The next thing on my mind was a, be prepared, a macro e.g.

```
#define GENERATE_BACKEND(...)
    ...
```

that would just substitute for the prefix. But I do not like that. It does not feel like 
modern C++.

One other thing I could do is group everything toghether in one class template and 
do tag dispatching or use enable_if, e.g.

```
template <typename Component>
class backend
{
public:

    ...
    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Component, bull_component>::value>::type>
    void get_data (uint8_t* buffer)
    {
       error_details_t err;
       bull_get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
    }

    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Component, frog_component>::value>::type>
    void get_data (uint8_t* buffer)
    {
       error_details_t err;
       frog_get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
    }

    template<typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_same<Component, bullfrog_component>::value>::type>
    void get_data (uint8_t* buffer)
    {
       error_details_t err;
       bullfrog_get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
    }
    ...

private:
    typename Component::handle_type handle;
};

struct frog_component
{
   using handle_type = frog_handle_t*;
};

struct bull_component
{
   using handle_type = bull_handle_t*;
};

struct bullfrog_component
{
   using handle_type = bullfrog_handle_t*;
};

using frog_backend = backend<frog_component>;
using bull_backend = backend<bull_component>;
using bullfrog_backend = backend<bullfrog_component>;
```

Still it doesn't feel right. One other thing that bothers me besides the apparent code 
duplication is that, except for the macro version :), they do not scale nice with 
the addition of C components.

I'm always under the impression that there must be something else which is better.
So, does anyone know of a better, worthier of the modern C++ name, technique to handle 
this type of situation?

Comment: template and Function pointer ?

Comment: I do not understand the downvotes. Please be at least polite and explain.

Comment: @Jarod42 could you provide an example?

Comment: Either is the wrong time of the day for some people or there must be something really wrong with the question and I am blind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I have in mind is

```
template <typename H> using create_t = void (*)(H**, error_details_t*);
template <typename H> using destroy_t = void (*)(H*, error_details_t*);
template <typename H> using get_data_t = void (*)(H*, uint8_t* buffer, error_details_t*);

template <typename H,
          create_t<H> create,
          destroy_t<H> destroy,
          get_data_t<H> get_data>
class backend
{
    backend() { error_details_t err; create(&handle, err);}
    ~backend() {  error_details_t err; destroy(handle, err);}

    backend(const backend&) = delete;
    backend& operator =(const backend&) = delete;
    backend(backend&&) = delete;
    backend& operator =(backend&&) = delete;

    void get_data(uint8_t* buffer)
    {
         error_details_t err;
         get_data(handle, buffer, &err);
    }

private:
   H* handle = nullptr;
};

using bull = backend<bull_handle_t, &bull_create, &bull_destroy, &bull_get_data>;
using frog = backend<frog_handle_t, &frog_create, &frog_destroy, &frog_get_data>;
using bullfrog = backend<bullfrog_handle_t,
                         &bullfrog_create,
                         &bullfrog_destroy,
                         &bull_get_data>;
```

Maybe `error_details_t` can be a member,
and you should also handle error.

Comment: This is indeed interesting. I think I can work further with that. I was already thinking about function pointers but I was not sure how and with what to "combine" them.

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that @Jarod42 was implying something

```
template <typename T>
class component
{
private:
    typedef void (*destroyMethod)(T*,error_details_t*);
    ...
public:
    component(destroyMethod,...)
    {
        destroy = destroyMethod;
        ...
    }
    void Destroy()
    {
        error_details_t err;
        destroy(handle, err);
    }
    ...
private:
    destroyMethod destroy;
    T * handle;
};
```

then instanciate with something like:

```
component<bull_handle_t> yourBull(bull_destroy, ...)
```

And you could probably wrap away the last part with some extra work

Comment: But there is more than one function in the API. Should I pass function pointers for each and everyone of them? How does that scale if I add more functions to the API?

Comment: If the component class youd have to mirror each type, as long as the interface of your different types doesn't diverge from eachother the scaling would be linear with the size of the interface. You should look at the code @Jarod42 supplied though since it puts the functions into the template declaration wich would allow you to make a nice typedef to reduce each instanciation a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You have a collection of C functions arranged in groups, with names and signatures that follow a consistent pattern.  If you want your C++ wrapper to call one of those functions, the function's name must appear one way or another in the C++ code.  Your choices for accomplishing that are to insert the names literally in the appropriate places in your wrapper code, or to generate them systematically via macros.  You have rejected both alternatives.

If you insist on avoiding macros, you could consider writing a code generator to output C++ sources for all the class definitions (that call the needed functions literally).  Perhaps that would be more satisfying than coding it all by hand, and it would allow you to easily regenerate the classes if they turn out to be flawed, if the C library changes or adds functions, or for any other reason.

Comment: I have not rejected anything yet. I'm weighing the alternatives and I'm also wondering if people have come with better ideas, hence the question.

Comment: @celavek, there are no other options, just variations on the ones you already know.